# IPC Mechanism for large messages and also preserves message boundary

Tags: linux, udp, ipc, message-queue, unix-socket

Is there any in built mechanism in linux for passing large messages with preserving the message boundaries?

I know Posix Queues, Unix socket.

On Posix queue there is limitation on the message size.

With Unix Socket:
if I go with SOCK_STREAM, there is no limit on size but it will not preserve message boundary.
if I go with SOCK_DGRAM, this will preserve message boundary but if receiving side does not have enough buffer size then the rest of the message will be discarded.

I am looking for some robust way to achieve this. Any suggestions will be helpful.